# Adjust width of vuetify datatable "rows per page" menu width because text is truncated

Tags: css, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

How do I ensure that text in the rows per page menu isn't truncated?

In firefox 60.5 with vuetify 1.4.1, when I go to change the rows per page, I noticed that the menu was cutting off "100".

I tried changing it from this:

```
<v-data-table
  ...
  :rows-per-page-items="[5,10,25,50,100]"
  ...
/>
```

to this:

```
<v-data-table
   ...
   :rows-per-page-items="[{text:'5', value:5},...,{text:'100', value:100}]"
  ...
/>
```

thinking that having the text would make a difference--it didn't.

**UPDATE**:
Also, within `<style scoped> ... </style>`, I tried many combinations of the following with no success:

```
/deep/ .v-list__tile__title {min-width: 30px;}
/deep/ .v-list__tile {min-width: 30px;}
/deep/ .v-list__tile__content {min-width: 30px;}
/deep/ .v-list__tile__title {min-width: 30px;}
/deep/ .v-select-list {min-width: 80px;}
/deep/ .v-menu__content{min-width: 80px;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not ideal, I made a global style instead of a scoped one.  In other words, I went from `<style scoped> ... </style>` to `<style> ... </style>`.

In this particular case I used:

```
<style> 
  .v-list__tile__title { 
    min-width: 3em;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set it in your data and access it in the table. Like so:

```
data: () => ({
  pagination: {
    descending: true,
    page: 1,
    rowsPerPage: 5,
    totalItems: 0,
    rowsPerPageItems: [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
  },
})
```

then when you set your data table:

```
<v-data-table
  ...
  :pagination.sync="pagination"
  :rows-per-page-items="pagination.rowsPerPageItems"
  :total-items="pagination.totalItems"
  ...
>
```

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. `"[{text:'5', value:5},...,{text:'100', value:100}]"` was just shorthand. Kind of like in a math proof. Also, I actually have it set in data...I just didn't feel like typing it all out.  My problem is that when I click on the menu to select rows per page, the rest of the numbers show up just fine, but 100 show up as "1..."